# GeoJSON is valid according to JSONLint but jquery gives error

Tags: leaflet, geojson, ajax

I have the following GeoJSON (from webservice)

```
{
"Features": [
    {
        "Id": "1",
        "Geometry": {
            "Coordinates": [
                {
                    "Latitude": 31.2812,
                    "Longitude": 34.8027,
                    "Altitude": 0
                }
            ],
            "Type": 0,
            "CRS": null,
            "BoundingBoxes": null
        },
        "Properties": {
            "Color": "#00FF55"
        },
        "Type": 7,
        "CRS": null,
        "BoundingBoxes": null
    },
    {
        "Id": "2",
        "Geometry": {
            "Coordinates": [
                {
                    "Latitude": 31.7825,
                    "Longitude": 35.1966,
                    "Altitude": 0
                }
            ],
            "Type": 0,
            "CRS": null,
            "BoundingBoxes": null
        },
        "Properties": {
            "Color": "#FF5500"
        },
        "Type": 7,
        "CRS": null,
        "BoundingBoxes": null
    }
],
"Type": 8,
"CRS": null,
"BoundingBoxes": null
```

}

This is the webservice code :

```
public string GetItemsFromDBGeoJSON()
{
    List<GeoJSON.Net.Feature.Feature> fList = new List<GeoJSON.Net.Feature.Feature>();
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.GetGPSData", conn))
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                string name = (string)reader["GPSUserName"];
                double lon = Convert.ToDouble(((decimal)reader["Lon"]));
                double lat = Convert.ToDouble(((decimal)reader["Lat"]));
                string clr = (string)reader["GPSUserColor"];

                GeoJSON.Net.Geometry.GeographicPosition latlon = new GeoJSON.Net.Geometry.GeographicPosition(lat,lon,0);
                GeoJSON.Net.Geometry.Point point = new GeoJSON.Net.Geometry.Point(latlon);                    

                Dictionary<string,object> properties = new Dictionary<string,object>();
                properties.Add("Color", clr);
                GeoJSON.Net.Feature.Feature feature = new GeoJSON.Net.Feature.Feature(point, properties);
                feature.Id = name;                    

                fList.Add(feature);
            }
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
    GeoJSON.Net.Feature.FeatureCollection fCol = new GeoJSON.Net.Feature.FeatureCollection(fList);
    JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

    return serializer.Serialize(fCol);
}
```

The Ajax call gives me error :

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character
```

Here is the request using JQuery

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost:36361/Service.asmx/GetItemsFromDBGeoJSON",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (response) {
        console.log('success');
    },
    error: function (req, status, error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```

Also , Using Firebug Console , I see this response from the request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">{"Features":[{"Id":"1","Geometry":{"Coordinates":[{"Latitude":31.2812,"Longitude":34.8027,"Altitude":0}],"Type":0,"CRS":null,"BoundingBoxes":null},"Properties":{"Color":"#00FF55"},"Type":7,"CRS":null,"BoundingBoxes":null},{"Id":"2","Geometry":{"Coordinates":[{"Latitude":31.7825,"Longitude":35.1966,"Altitude":0}],"Type":0,"CRS":null,"BoundingBoxes":null},"Properties":{"Color":"#FF5500"},"Type":7,"CRS":null,"BoundingBoxes":null}],"Type":8,"CRS":null,"BoundingBoxes":null}</string>
```

Any idea why ? I want to show it on leaflet layer.

Comment: could you post your jquery code?

Comment: @Simo : Edited my post with the jquery code.

Comment: Where does this geojson come from ? The syntax is really strange, e.g. '"Type": 8' should be something like '"Type":FeatureCollection'.Try cleaning it with http://geojsonlint.com/, remove the upper case lettre, etc

Comment: @FredB : I'm using GeoJSON.net , I'll add that code also.

Comment: @FredB :  I've added the code , even if my geojson not valid , I don't understand why the json itself gives me bad result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, from firebug console, it seems the returned content is not pure json but a mix of xml and json ....

Be sure the url passed in ajax call return pure json and it will work fine.

Comment: I've added "contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8;"," and now it works.